# Autoload and namespace in the inheritance and composition

Tags: php, inheritance, namespaces, autoload

I wrote an Autoload:

```
<?php
function autoload($class)
{
    try
    {   
        global $path;
        $elements = explode("\\", $class); 
        $name_class = end($elements); 

        foreach ($elements as $element)
            {   
                if($element != $name_class)
                    {
                        $path .= $element."/"; 
                        echo "path:".$path."<br/>";
                    }
            }

        $file = strtolower(($path).$name_class.".php");  
        if(file_exists($file))
        {
              include($file);
              return;
        }
         throw new Exception($class." not founded");
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return;
    }
}

class Autoloader
{
    public static function autoload($class)
    {
        autoload($class);
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload');
spl_autoload_register(array('autoloader', 'autoload'));
?>
```

The Autoload finds a relative path and change it in an absolute path.

Now I have problem when I call a class from another file with different namespace.

For example if I have this file Base.php in the directorynamed framework:

```
namespace Framework;

use Framework\Inspector as Inspector;

 class Base
    {
        private $_inspector;

        public function __construct($options = array())
        {
            $this->_inspector = new Inspector($this);
...
```

Now I have the file Inspector.php in the same directory with the same namespace:

```
<?php
namespace Framework;

    use Framework\ArrayMethods as ArrayMethods;
    use Framework\StringMethods as StringMethods;
    use \Exception as Exception;

    class Inspector
    {
...
?>
```

When I try to instantiate the class Base, I get the exception message about missing Inspector class.

The same think if I try to extend Base class in other directories. I tried to add some echoes in my autoload function and it printed that he use local namespace of the child class or a class who uses an instance by composition of another class to create the string for finding the php file.

For example when I try the load Inspector in Base with echo I got:

```
path:Framework/
file:::C:\LightTPD\htdocs\mvc\framework\framework\Base.php (I add some ::: to make more readable)
framework/base.php


path:Framework/Framework/
file:::
framework/framework/inspector.php (trying to use the namespace of inspector after using the one of Base)


Framework\Inspector not foundedpath:Framework/Framework/Framework/
file:::
framework/framework/framework/inspector.php

Framework\Inspector not founded
```

When I tried to extend class Base by class Driver I got this:

```
path:Framework/
path:Framework/Configuration/
file:::C:\LightTPD\htdocs\mvc\framework\framework\configuration\Driver.php
framework/configuration/driver.php (everything ok)


path:Framework/Configuration/Framework/ (Framework is from Base; Configuration/Framework is from driver)
file:::
framework/configuration/framework/base.php 


Framework\Base not foundedpath:Framework/Configuration/Framework/Framework/
file:::
framework/configuration/framework/framework/base.php


Framework\Base not founded
```

-###############################################################
The directory tree is:

It's:

```
-framework: ArrayMethods.php, Base.php,Configuration.php, Inspector.php, StingMethods.php
           -configuration: Driver.php
                -exception
           -core
                -exception
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you already added your application path to the php include path? Can you give a much clearer view of your directory structure/tree?

Comment: Why I need to do that and after how I can include it on a server?

The autoload simply find using namespace and gets the absolute path to include it. Why do I need set include path?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I noticed that the problem was the global $path.

Now I wrote the autoload.php in this way:

```
<?php
function autoload($class)
{
    try
    {   $path = NULL;
        $elements = explode("\\", $class); 
        $name_class = end($elements); 

        foreach ($elements as $element)
            {   
                if($element != $name_class)
                    {
                        $path .= $element."/"; 
                        $file = realpath(strtolower(($path).$name_class.".php"));  //realpath is optional 
                        if(file_exists($file))
                                {
                                      include($file);                       
                                      //echo $file."<br><br>"; testing in for debugging
                                      return;
                                }
                    }
            }   
       throw new Exception($class." not founded");
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return;
    }
}

class Autoloader
{
    public static function autoload($class)
    {
        autoload($class);
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload');
spl_autoload_register(array('autoloader', 'autoload'));
?>
```

Now even if it's less perfomant everything it's ok, he work whatever a class call another, it's based only the namespace of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the files path of the class you want to extend(parent class) from to your child class file before the use namespaces of the parent/Base class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).